# How to repeat this process for many more numbers using for loop?

Tags: javascript

I want to repeat this process using `for` loop if I put many more numbers like

```
var string = ["+919999999999","+918888888888","+917777777777"];
```

here is my code:

```
var string = "+919999999999";
document.write(string.slice(-10));
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what research you've done into the issue and what attempts you've made to solve the issue yourself. There are many questions on how to loop through an array on Stack Overflow already...

Comment: thanks sir, now is this right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you have 3 different ways

```js
var numbers = ["+919999999999","+918888888888","+917777777777"];
console.log("------ 1 ");
for(let number of numbers){
  console.log(number.slice(-10))
}
console.log("------ 2");

for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
  console.log(numbers[i].slice(-10));
}
console.log("------ 3");

numbers.forEach(n => console.log(n.slice(-10)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```js
let strings = ["+919999999999","+918888888888","+917777777777"];

strings.forEach(str => {
  return document.write(str.slice(-10) + "<br/>");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = ["+919999999999","+918888888888","+917777777777"];

items.forEach(item => document.write(item.slice(-10)))
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a solution as far as i understand the problem

```
 var string = "+919999999999";
    
    let numToMinus='1',
    str2=string.slice(-10)
    
    for (let i=0;i<str2.length-1;i++){
        numToMinus=numToMinus+'1'
    }
    
    let list=["+919999999999"]
    for(let i=0;i<numToMinus.length-1;i++){
        str2= parseFloat(str2)-parseFloat(numToMinus)
    
        list.push("+91"+str2)
    }
    
    console.log(list)
```

;